# Can you create an OpenGL texture array that has only one layer?

Tags: arrays, opengl, textures

I am trying to clean up an OpenGL application. Currently, I want to store all my textures in a [texture array](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture).
According to cases, I might have to store only one texture.
In that case, can I create a valid array texture with only one layer ? I did not find which part of the spec deals with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a texture array with only one layer.